# VS Code without Internet access is lagging on Linux, are there any settings to try in order to improve

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

We want to use VS Code on Linux machines for writing code. The Linux machines are by design not connected to the Internet.

Code lags when run on Linux. We have tried to disable extensions and disable gpu-rendering. Nothing helps. Any suggestions for reducing/eliminating lagging? We have seen it on Ubuntu 22.04 and on RHEL 8.6. Tips for troubleshooting are most welcome?

Regards